# form instance not displayed in widgets

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

views.py

```
def save_report(request):
    form = ReporterRegisterForm()
    profileform = ProfilecontactForm()
    user = request.user
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        user = User.objects.get(pk=id)        
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user.id)
        form = ReporterRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=user) 
        profileform = ProfilecontactForm(request.POST,instance = userprofile)
        if form.is_valid() and profileform.is_valid(): 
            form.save()
            profilesave = profileform.save(commit=False)            
            profilesave.save()
    return render(request, 'setting/edit_reporter.html',
                   {'form': form,
                     'userprofile':userprofile
                    })
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'setting.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),      
    (r'^save-reporter/$', 'save_reporter'),)
```

js:

```
$('.reporter').click(function () {       
        alert(1)     
        var id = $(this).attr('id');  
        var csrf_token = $("#csrf_token").val();
        $.ajax({ 
           data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: ('{{csrf_token}}'),   
               // form:form.serialize(),            
                id:id,

                },
        type:'POST',
        url: '/setting/save-reporter/',
        success: function() {
            $('#authorisedreporter').show();
        }
      });
     });
```

html:

```
<button type="button" id="{{ list.0.id }}" class="openDiv">{{list.0.name}} </button>
```

{{ list.0.id }} id from list is the id in user table

This is my views.py to update the forms data.I want to instantiate the forms data,need to show the field in update mode.It is not getting instantiated.I am getting the right id from POST.Need help

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you're at no point returning the ProfileContactForm object, so it's not being rendered right?

Comment: @MikkoP,it an edit problem,Rohan's answer is showing the logged user's instance.But i want to display the instance of user getting from ajax post.I am getting the right id from ajax post,but in console if i see it in html,i am getting the form error message as "This field is required" instead of showing the instance the field is empty.Can you help me with this

Comment: Could you share the code for this view from urls.py?

Comment: @MikkoP urls.py shared

Comment: Since you don't include the user id you plan to edit into the url, how did you plan to access it? I would change it to something like this:

urls.py
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', myapp.views.save_report, name='save_report'),
views.py
def save_report(request, pk):
 ...

Now can simply refer to pk (which in this case would be a user id passed on from the ajax call.

Could you show the ajax call as well. Right now I have no idea how you're passing the user id information on to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to populate form with `request.user`. If you want to populate for some other user, you need to get id from url, and then retrieve that `user` and `userprofile`.

So your view can be updated as

```
def save_report(request):
    user = request.user
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
    form = ReporterRegisterForm(instance=user)
    profileform = ProfilecontactForm(instance=userprofile)

    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = ReporterRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=user) 
        profileform = ProfilecontactForm(request.POST,instance = userprofile)
        if form.is_valid() and profileform.is_valid(): 
            form.save()
            profilesave = profileform.save(commit=False)            
            profilesave.save()
    return render(request, 'setting/edit_reporter.html',
                   {'form': form,
                     'userprofile':userprofile
                    })
```

Comment: I used your snippet,it is showing the current user's(logged user's) instance.I want to show the instance of another user.I am getting another user's id from ajax post.I need to instantiate that users detail.How to  continue that.

Comment: @Royal, As I said in answer, you need to get `id` from the url and then get appropriate user instance using that.

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I'd do it:

Include this in your html template (and hide it if you want with display: none). my_id is a context variable that you'd have to pass on somehow.

`<div id="save-url" rel="{% url "save_reporter" pk=my_id %}" ></div>`

Then in you ajax call you can fetch the url:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: $('#save-url').attr('rel'),
...
```

Your url would look like this:

```
url(r'^save-reporter/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', myapp.views.save_report, name='save_report'),
```

And your view like this:

```
views.py def save_report(request, pk):
     user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
```

Now pk is the user id that you've passed on from the ajax call.
By the way the url you posted refers to save_reporter and the function is called save_report.

P.S. No offense, but you should take a wee bit more time to formulate your question as clearly as possible and include the relevant information.

Edit: Gotcha. That is interesting. I would've thought you'd be able to access the id with what you have, but you could try

```
id = request.POST['id']
```

In any case it's not a very "Django" way of doing things, you should include the id in the url (see my answer above).

Comment: I will try with the help of you sample,if help needed will comment you.

Comment: I am showing the userprofile detail in template in a table format.I placed a button for username,if username button is clicked the hidden div should open with the userprofile shown in table format,that is as form field instance.This is i am trying to do

Comment: So you have several forms on your template. Listen, I'm afraid I'll have to stop here as it sounds like your code is structurally a bit flawed. How about creating buttons that redirect the user to an UpdateView where the url parameter corresponds to the UserProfile you want to update. Also, you should include a snippet from your templates.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,i don't have idea how to do,i had created github for my source code,i had noticed the line also.Please refer and guide me in correct way https://github.com/Royalreena/Django

Comment: Sorry but this is far too big a project to start guiding through in detail. I think what you should do is have a list of all the reporters with an "edit" button next to them. This edit button will then redirect you to an UpdateView (see Django documentation). The url of the UpdateView should contain the id of the user to be edited. The UpdateView would obviously contain the form. Working with multiple form objects is a bit tricky in Django and generating them dynamically even more so, so I'd advise against it unless you really know what you're doing.